# Display images from database, but only if request comes through a secured page

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

I have inherited a web application that displays a "photo roster" of students enrolled in a class. These images are protected by various regulations, so the rosters are only available to the instructor of the class. The images are stored as binary data in a SQL Server database,

In the original design, the images were served through a web handler file (.ashx) that returned an image based on a student ID value. The roster page limited users to selecting courses that were appropriate for them, thus protecting the images.

Now some administrators have learned to call the web handler file directly by modifying the URL. I would like to prevent this, and instead send the administrators through another protected page that limits their access based on business rules.

What options do I have for locking down the web handler/web service to only respond to requests that are embedded in a managed page? How can I prevent users from calling the handler directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the Authentication/Authorization logic inside the handler like this.

For example, the following code will display 404 error, if user is not login.

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState 
{
    // 1x1 transparent GIF
    private readonly byte[] GifData =
    {
        0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61,
        0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff,
        0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
        0x02, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3b
    };

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //if (context.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
            context.Response.Buffer = false;
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(GifData, 0, GifData.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Write("File not found.");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the response. I am already enforcing windows authentication through IIS. Problem is that authorization requires specific pairing of user and course info. I suppose I could do additional authorization querying in the handler, but that seems like a lot of extra work. Hoping to just verify that the request came thru the form.